# What do these numbers `10k`, `6k`, `1k`, `210` in java eclipse code completion mean?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-luna

What do `10k`, `6k`, `1k` and `210` mean in this eclipse Luna code completion popup. It appeared when I was trying to override a method from a custom class in a custom class.

[image]

Comment: I have a feeling it would probably be decided to go to Programmer's Exchange only because it is a question about Eclipse's output, and nothing to do with Java exactly

Comment: Questions about software development tools are on-topic for StackOverflow

Comment: Yup, on-topic. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: What exact build are you using? I'm using 4.4.1 and I don't see that.

Comment: This could also come from a installed feature. I suppose thats a calculated  count of uses in your workspace or something similar

Comment: If I had to take a guess -- and this is only a guess -- I'd guess it's the number of times each method has been overridden in your code. Tons of classes override `toString`, fewer override `hashCode`. We don't see the number for `equals`, but I'd guess it's also 6k. `clone` and `finalize` get overridden less often.

Comment: ok I dont think its number of times each method has been overridden in my code since my codebase is exceedingly small

Answer (score 3):

That is a certain plugin at work, either [Code Recommenders](http://eclipse.org/recommenders/) or something similar.

Basically, it's (crowd sourced) information that tells you how often or likely a certain method is called or overridden.

Comment: yess I guess now. I think its either Codetrails Connect Hippie Completion plugin or Eclipse Code Recommenders Snipmatch plugin that I recently installed in eclipse, just wish that they could have shown some on hover tooltip explaining what it is

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, The greater the number to the right of a method, the greater the probability that you'll use that method in that context, as calculated by some weird algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

These numbers come from our [Codetrails Connect Hippie Completion](http://www.codetrails.com/connect).

It shows how often developers call or override methods and suggests them in order of frequency. In this case, Object.equals() was overridden about 10.000 times, while Object.hashCode() was overridden about 6.000 times.

The data comes from users of Codetrails Connect who decided to share  their code completion events with us. We then aggregate those events and provide the resulting information back to our users.

You can adjust the way these numbers are shown at *Preferences > Codetrails Connect > Hippie - Relevance Indicator Settings*. Instead of the default "Heatmap", you can elect to show absolute, unrounded numbers with "Simple (m/n)" or show the relative "Percentage" for proposals.